# OpenVPN Chain (Bridge tun0 and tun1 same server)

Tags: network, vpn, openvpn

I have three Linode VMs set up as an exercise like so:

[image]

I am able to connect the ubuntu client machine to ubuntu serverA via vpn. I am also able to connect serverA as an openvpn client to ubuntu serverB. However, I am stuck on how to route all traffic back and forth from client machine to serverB? I have tried forwarding on iptables, redirecting getway def1 on client, etc.

Does anyone know of a good resource to learn how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: You're asking how to route traffic, this is not a security question. VPNs fall under security, correct. But asking how to route traffic from one machine to a server is not a security problem.